# The curl of a vector field using one-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am trying to solve the following exercise of Barden's book:

[image]

You will need this other exercise to solve the first one.

[image]

I think I managed to do the first one ( *(i)* ) correctly. Now, about the  $\theta^{-1}*d\theta(X)$ part of the second exercise( *(ii)* ): I managed to get the result that I know is correct - $\theta^{-1}*d\theta(X)=\nabla\times X$. However, I do not know how to justify some of the steps of my proof: I accepted them temporarily just so that I could get to the result. Here is the outline of my proof, along with the questions that arose:

$$\theta(X)=\theta(a^ie_i)\overset{1}{=}a^i\theta(e_i)\overset{2}{=}a^idx_i\,(\in \Omega^1(U))$$
Now
$$d\theta(X)=d(a^idx_i)=...=da^idx_i$$
So
$$*dv(X)=*(da^idx_i)=...=\Big( \frac{\partial a^3}{\partial x_1} - \frac{\partial a^2}{\partial x_3}\Big)dx_1 + ... + \Big( \frac{\partial a^2}{\partial x_1} - \frac{\partial a^1}{\partial x_2}\Big)dx_3$$
Hence
$$\theta^{-1}(*dv(X))\overset{3}{=} \Big( \frac{\partial a^3}{\partial x_1} - \frac{\partial a^2}{\partial x_3}\Big)e_1 + ... + \Big( \frac{\partial a^2}{\partial x_1} - \frac{\partial a^1}{\partial x_2}\Big)e_3=\nabla\times X$$

*Questions (referent to the numbered equality signs):*

*1)* I know that $\theta$ is an isomorphism and hence linear. But what does it mean when the "vector space" it acts on is $\mathcal{X}(U)$? As far as I understand, $\mathcal{X}(U)$ is not really a vector space, but a module, the underlying ring being $\mathcal{C}^\infty(U)$... So does linearity of $\theta$ mean that $\theta(f\omega_1+g\omega_2)=f\theta(\omega_1)+g\theta(\omega_2)$? (I am not very familiar with  modules).

*2)* Is this valid? I do not see why, though it seems natural.

*3)* Again, I use that $\theta(e_i)=dx_i$, so answering 2 probably answers this one.

Comment: Yes and yes.  When we say that a map of $R$-modules is linear, we mean the same thing as when we say that a map of $k$-vector spaces is linear: the map plays nicely with scalar (ring element) multiplication and addition.  For question (2), check the relation that defines the correspondence between 1-forms and vector fields.  Is it true that $dx_i|_p(v) = \langle e_i,v\rangle$ for every vector $v$?  If so, then $dx_i=\theta(e_i)$.

Comment: 1: How do you know $\theta$ is a (module) isomorphism? (I mean, if you really knew this you wouldn't be asking the question)

Comment: @mathematician Far enough: I "know" that in the sense that I was told so, and I guess this is a special kind of module in which we can write the elements as linear combinations of a basis where the coefficients are elements of the ring. That is, I just think of it as a vector space whose scalars are functions, in this particular case. I know nothing else.

Comment: @AustinChristian Very helpful, thank you.

Comment: It might be helpful to your understanding to prove $\theta$ is in fact a $C^\infty(U)$-module isomorphism from $\mathcal{X}(U)$ to $\Omega^1(U)$.  That is, show that it has the properties that you're using (you can move elements of $C^\infty(U)$ through $\theta$).